# Unwanted quantize markers in logic pro

Tags: logic-pro

When flexing a region in Logic 9, you are probably familiar with the grey transient markers that logic creates. Also, if you choose to quantize the region logic creates white quantize markers. The white markers are not supposed to show up unless you choose to quantize the region. My region's quantize setting is set to off(3840), but quantize markers show up anyway. Does anyone know how to remove the white markers in any other way than manually right-clicking and choosing 'Delete flex marker' on each and every one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I solved this myself. I realized that as soon as I click a quantize marker (not transient marker) and move it slightly, it turns into a flex marker, and all quantize markers to the left of my brand new flex marker disappear. Transient markers are still there though. Perfect. They just shouldn't have been there in the first place.

Comment: Well, but it work only until another flex marker. So, if you manually flex all the track, then the quantize markers appear again (it happened to me), how to remove all those white markers quickly ?

Answer (score 1):

Never seen this happen, but you could try double clicking the audio region to bring it up in the sample editor. Then click the transient editor button to highlight, and try clicking the left arrow until it gets rid of the markers you don't want.

Will also say that if Logic is acting glitchy, you should click Preferences>Initialize All Except Key Commands. Works like a charm.

E

Comment: It looks like with the transient editor button highlighted, the minus button (which I suppose you are referring to), only removes transient markers. Not quantize markers. So unfortunately, this solution didn't work for me.

I also tried the _Preferences>Initialize All Except Key Commands_. Didn't work either. Didn't know about this command before, so thanks anyway.